# Deploying an Meteor app with mup - error: no configs found for meteor

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, meteor-up

I've been trying to deploy a meteor app to Digital Ocean. I've configured mup.js like this:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '[droplet ip address]',
      username: '[username]',
      password: '[password]'
    }
  },

  // Install MongoDB on the server. Does not destroy the local MongoDB on future setups
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: nodeVersion defaults to 0.10.36 if omitted. Do not use v, just the version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",

  // Install PhantomJS on the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Application name (no spaces).
  "appName": "pichaprint",

  // Location of app (local directory). This can reference '~' as the users home directory.
  // i.e., "app": "~/Meteor/my-app",
  // This is the same as the line below.
  "app": ".",

  // Configure environment
  // ROOT_URL must be set to https://YOURDOMAIN.com when using the spiderable package & force SSL
  // your NGINX proxy or Cloudflare. When using just Meteor on SSL without spiderable this is not necessary
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://pichaprint.com",
  },

  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
};
```

When I try to run `mup setup`, I get the following error:
`error: no configs found for meteor`

I'm currently working live by using PuTTY and I'm within the meteor project folder which contains the `mup.js` file (that's the reason the app property value is a period). What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that even though I initialized mup by entering `mup init`, it did not actually generate a mup.json. So I had to create that manually by entering the following command: `cat > mup.json` in the root of my project folder